# Replacing a character with a count variable in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

My current code is as the below. The replace function is achieving another goal and cannot be changed.

```
with open('file.gff', 'r') as f:

     GFF = f.read()

data = ''
extract = re.compile(r'gene\W\d+\W\d+\W.\W.\W.*;')
it = extract.finditer(GFF)

for match in it:
      data += '\n|*' + (match.group(0))

line = ''
count = 1132033.5 #it must begin with this number
for i in data:
     line += i.replace('|', str(count)).replace('*','\t')
     count = count + 1
print(line)
```

The first few entries in the file Data is as below.

```
|*gene  1   1524    .   +   .   ID=gene:Rv0001;Name=dnaA;biotype=protein_coding;description=Chromosomal replication initiator protein DnaA;gene_id=Rv0001;
|*gene  2052    3260    .   +   .   ID=gene:Rv0002;Name=dnaN;biotype=protein_coding;description=DNA polymerase III (beta chain) DnaN (DNA nucleotidyltransferase);gene_id=Rv0002;
|*gene  3280    4437    .   +   .   ID=gene:Rv0003;Name=recF;biotype=protein_coding;description=DNA replication and repair protein RecF (single-strand DNA binding protein);gene_id=Rv0003;
|*gene  4434    4997    .   +   .   ID=gene:Rv0004;biotype=protein_coding;description=Conserved hypothetical protein;gene_id=Rv0004;
|*gene  5240    7267    .   +   .   ID=gene:Rv0005;Name=gyrB;biotype=protein_coding;description=DNA gyrase (subunit B) GyrB (DNA topoisomerase (ATP-hydrolysing)) (DNA topoisomerase II) (type II DNA topoisomerase);gene_id=Rv0005;
```

The output is as below.

```
>>>1132033.5      gene        1       1524
   1132177.5      gene        2052    3260
   1132342.5      gene        3280    4437
```

I don't understand why the desired output, as below, is not being generated.

```
>>>1132033.5      gene        1       1524
   1132134.5      gene        2052    3260
   1132335.5      gene        3280    4437
```

I hope someone can help!

Comment: What is "data"? Is the output really only three lines long?

Comment: 'data' is a large .GTF file that I am parsing, for that reason I spliced the output so only 3 lines were printed.

Comment: Are you sure that each line of data contains a "|"?

Comment: Yes I'm sure because I edited it that way so that it would be there for me to replace with the number.

Comment: This could happen if `data` contained elements that didn't add anything to `line`.  I suggest you post code that compiles and is complete.

Comment: Thanks @DennisSparrow I have now added the first few lines of 'data' for reference as well as the code I have compiled so far.

Comment: It's still not complete and compilable.  I tweaked it enough to compile and tested and did not reproduce your result.  I got no output.  The regular expression did not match anything.  I suspect this is because the `.*` matches any number of any character and after that, there is no `;` left to match.  You can try again to post something that compiles and reproduces your result.

Comment: After learning more about regular expressions, I no longer think the `.*` is gobbling up the `;`.

Answer (score 0):

The `for match in it:` loop constructs `data` as a string.

So `for i in data:` iterates over every character in the string.  Most of the time, the `i.replace(...` expression in this loop doesn't find anything to replace and just returns i.  But whether it does anything or not, `count` gets incremented for every character in `data`.  That's why the output values of `count` go up by more than 1.  It is counting characters, not lines.

There are multiple ways you could get a count of lines rather than characters.  I will sketch one that needs relatively little change to what you have now.

You constructed `data` to have a newline character (`\n`)at the beginning of each line, so if you only increment `count` when `i` is `\n`, it will count lines rather than characters.  This won't quite work, because the very first character in `data` will be a newline, so the number generated when the loop sees the following `|` character will be 1132034.5, which is 1 more than you want in the first line of your output.  To fix that, you could either initialize `count` to a value that is lower by 1, that is, 1132032.5, before the loop, or you could change your construction of `data` to put the newline characters at the ends of lines rather than the beginnings, if the output will still be acceptable with that change.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way for me to change the code, so that it I can include the count number at the beginning of each line, counting up by 1 for each line.

Comment: Thank you I used .split lines by '\n' before the count and it worked perfectly!!